# Selecting Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A special deck of 51 cards constists of 25 pairs and 1 wild card. The deck is distrubuted evenly between 3 players (17 cards each). What is the probability that your hand has only two pairs that is the probability you have 13 single cards.

My reasoning was I have $51 \choose 17$ hands. There are $25 \choose 2$ ways to selcect two pairs. There are $51 \choose 4$ ways to select 4 cards. Im having trouble counting the single cards though. How many ways can I choose 13 single cards is where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once two pairs have been selected, the remainder of the deck consists of $23$ pairs and the wild card.

- Suppose that your hand does not contain the wild card; then you can fill it out by choosing $13$ of the $23$ remaining pairs, which can be done in $\binom{23}{13}$ ways, and then choosing one card from each of those pairs, which can be done in $2^{13}$ ways.
- I’ll leave to you the calculation for the case in which your hand **does** include the wild card; it’s quite similar.

Matter are a bit different if the wild card is truly wild and can be counted as half of a pair with any other card in the deck. In that case you have hands with two true pairs and $13$ singletons not including the wild card, and you have hands with one true pair, the wild card, and, and $14$ singletons. But the methods of counting are pretty much the same.